# How to visualize high-pass filtered images?

Tags: fourier-transform, highpass-filter, visualization

When I try visualizing a high-pass filtered image, all I see is gray, similar to the middle subfigure in the attached figure from a related paper. The authors claim they normalize the image to have unit variance, so I tried plotting $(x - \mu) / \sigma$, which still resulted in a gray image. Here is my process for high-pass filtering:

1. Shifted DFT
2. Apply radial mask, zero out low frequencies
3. Inverse shifted DFT
4. Normalize image to $[0, 1]$

[image]

Comment: Show your starting image -- it would have to have significant high-frequency content.  You might want to try something with known HF content (like the author's starting picture).  Did the authors say how they dealt with negative values?  By definition, $x - \mu$ is going to range around both sides of zero; for images you'd need to either take the absolute value or square that.

Comment: I'm working with private mammography data so I can't upload the image, but it has significant HF content. That's a good point about negative values, but I also tried $x / \sigma$ and this also gave me a gray image. All the authors said was "In order to even visualize these high frequency features, we had normalize pixel statistics to have unit variance."

Comment: Wait.  If it's high-pass filtered $\mu$ should be zero -- why didn't either of us catch that?  Are you using the $\sigma$ from before the high-pass filtering, or after?  (You need after).

Comment: I am using the $\sigma$ after the inverse DFT.

Comment: If you want to check the free gimp wavelet decomposition plugin it is awesome, the results are more graded... One of the images here shows a photo with invisible detail on some wavelengths: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1552&bih=807&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNRFtdFAzeywaFRDsWDqv_Tc7XKWIA%3A1571936130627&sa=1&ei=gtexXej5JZKua-S-paAM&q=gimp+wavelet+decomposition&oq=gimp+wavelet+decomposition&gs_l=img.3...3074.4880..5120...0.0..0.111.1109.12j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0i24.lrryIUGVs0w&ved=0ahUKEwjowrO1rrXlAhUS1xoKHWRfCcQQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=_1g7VhzDaA-xwM:

Answer (score 2):

First of all beware of the difference between image **sharpening** and **highpass** filtering. The former is actually a high frequency amplified image, while the latter removes the low frequency and completely eliminates the DC component.

So assuming that you indeed wanted to remove low frequency content by appling a highpass filter, then your output will be a *ghost* like image with black background that shows *image edges*.

Highpass filtering can produce *out of range* values, compared to the original valid range. This can be corrected with the following:

Assuming valid data range as [0,1], then the following assures that it will remain in [0,1] again:

```
x[m,n] = (x[m,n] - x_min)/(x_max-xmin)
```

Assuming valid data range as [0,255], then the following assures that it will remain in [0,255] again:

```
x[m,n] = 255*(x[m,n] - x_min)/(x_max-xmin)
```

More generally to map a data range from [a,b], into [c,d], the following mapping can be used:

```
x[m,n] = (d-c)*(x[m,n] - a)/(b-a) + c
```

Note that a range correction may not always yield a best looking image. You might as well need to adjust distribution of intensities in nonlinear ways to pop out requested features...

Comment: D'oh, that's a much better method than using $\sigma$.

Comment: @TimWescott  *mean* & *variance (std)* notation finds places in intuitive explanations; but here I preferred this other perspective...

Comment: It makes perfect sense, unless you've got an image that has a few really small outliers (because one white dot, one black dot, and a bunch of gray is just boring).

Comment: @TimWescott yes sometimes those outliers become real headaches...

Comment: I performed the first option you mentioned, which normalized the values to $[0 ,1]$. However, when I plot this, it appears to be all gray.

Comment: Please see the very right hand column of Figure 1 in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.08988.pdf. The gray box is exactly what I get, and the authors claim that a normalization produces the figure on the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

Very often, image display is driven by the initial data range (with inheritance). If the data is of `uint8` format (per channel), some software keep subsequent calculations in the same range, so value below $0$ and above $255$ (or $1$) are clipped. 
Conversion of initial data to float, or signed integer, can help. As well, take care of the scaling induced by the display function. In Matlab, `image` does $[0,255]$, and `imagecs` does a scaling to avoid down and up saturations. And flattens negative or too high data.

All the above processes are affine: centering + scaling. Leaving aside the management of negative or too-high values, diversity enhancement can help visualizations, like logarithms or power-law, like in homomorphic filtering.